# How to use fb ui message if the user created message in workflow?

Tags: facebook, fb.ui

I came to know that fb.ui message option wont work according to the latest fb program policies and they wrote like
"your application may only set this field if the user manually generated the content earlier in the workflow."

In website which is an application, user manually generates the content and it will be stored in a html textarea box.

How can I post the content generated in that textarea as message in feed ( fb.ui )

Please let me know if there is an option. 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Use the graph API and do an HTTP post to https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed with the message in the "message" form post parameter.

Comment: var body = 'Reading JS SDK documentation';
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
  } else {
    alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
  }
});